# Basic algebra: help needed with this equation

Tags: math, algebra

so it turns out I need highschool algebra afterall... and stupid me; I've forgotten how to do basic algebra.

I have this equation:

```
p = nc + s(n-1)
```

Therefore, for example:

```
c = (p - s(n-1)) / n
```

How can I solve the equation to resolve for s? ie, s = ??

thanks!

Comment: Are you doing this programmatically, or is this simply a math question? StackOverflow specifically relates to programming. There is [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) for math questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = (p - nc) / (n - 1)
```

In a detailed way:

```
    p = nc + s(n - 1)
=>  p - nc = s(n - 1)
=>  (p - nc) / (n - 1) = s
```

Comment: of course. I really could have figured that out. Like I said, highschool maths was a long time ago. :)  Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 5):

Of course you could ask wolfram-alpha next time

[(n*c) + s * (n-1) =p : solve for s](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n*c%29%20%2b%20s%20*%20%28n-1%29%20=p%20:%20solve%20for%20s)

Answer (score 2):

Great question!

Original:

```
p = nc + s( n- 1)
```

Subtract nc from both sides:

```
p - nc = s(n - 1)
```

Then divide both sides by (n-1)

```
(p - nc) / (n - 1) = s
```